# Как сделать нумерацию строк для текстового поля в tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

У меня есть текстовое поле со скролбаром:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

scroll=ttk.Scrollbar(root)
scroll.pack(fill=Y,side=RIGHT)

text=Text(root,yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
text.pack(fill=BOTH)

scroll.config(command=text.yview)

root.mainloop()
```

Вот результат:

[image: результат]

И я хотел слева от текстового поля сделать поле для нумерации строк  в текстовом поле. Я пробовал и Label и canvas , но ничего не работает. Можете подсказать как сделать нумерацию строк?

Comment: Для организации подобной фишки потребуется ОЧЕНЬ много строк кода.
Далеко не все продвинутые текстовые редакторы имеют нумерацию строк текста.

Comment: Само по себе это можно реализовать, единственная проблема - метки могут не совпадать по положению со строками текста в текстовом поле. Как вариант можно сделать два текстовых поля, второе (нередактируемое) для номеров строк, тогда номера будут совпадать по положению со строками текста (при условии что шрифт будет одинаковый по высоте).

Comment: @Assur я оцениваю объем кода для данной задачи в 100-200 строк (ну, максимум до 500). Это не очень много. И это не сверхсложная задача.

Comment: Тогда можете изложить ход задачи. Как именно можно реализовать нумерацию?

Comment: @Assur, 63 строки в итоге

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369470/tkinter-adding-line-number-to-text-widget

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделал немного не так как планировал: просто два текстовых поля и скролбар в гриде.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

# Перенос строк отключен, иначе нумерация будет работать некорректно
numbers = tk.Text(root, width=4, bg='lightgray', state=tk.DISABLED, relief=tk.FLAT)
numbers.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NS')

scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(root)
scroll.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='NS')


def on_yscrollcommand(*args):
    scroll.set(*args)  # Синхронизация скролбара с текстовым полем
    numbers.yview_moveto(args[0])  # Синхронизация поля с номерами с текстовым полем


text = tk.Text(root, yscrollcommand=on_yscrollcommand, wrap=tk.NONE)
text.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='NSWE')


def scroll_command(*args):
    # Движение скролбара управляет отображением текста в обоих текстовых полях
    text.yview(*args)
    numbers.yview(*args)


scroll.config(command=scroll_command)


def insert_numbers():
    count_of_lines = text.get(1.0, tk.END).count('\n') + 1
    
    numbers.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
    numbers.delete(1.0, tk.END)
    numbers.insert(1.0, '\n'.join(map(str, range(1, count_of_lines))))
    numbers.config(state=tk.DISABLED)


insert_numbers()


def on_edit(event):
    # Срабатывает при изменениях в текстовом поле
    insert_numbers()
    text.edit_modified(0)  # Сбрасываем флаг изменения текстового поля


text.bind('<<Modified>>', on_edit)

# Нужно чтобы текстовое поле автоматически меняло размер при изменении размера окна
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


# Для примера загружаем саму программу в редактор
import sys

with open(sys.argv[0]) as file:
    text.insert(1.0, file.read())

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: +1!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369470/tkinter-adding-line-number-to-text-widget) [@Bryan Oakley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7432):

```
import tkinter as tk


class TextLineNumbers(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.textwidget = None

    def attach(self, text_widget):
        self.textwidget = text_widget

    def redraw(self, *args):
        '''redraw line numbers'''
        self.delete("all")

        i = self.textwidget.index("@0,0")
        while True :
            dline= self.textwidget.dlineinfo(i)
            if dline is None: break
            y = dline[1]
            linenum = str(i).split(".")[0]
            self.create_text(2,y,anchor="nw", text=linenum)
            i = self.textwidget.index("%s+1line" % i)


class CustomText(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # create a proxy for the underlying widget
        self._orig = self._w + "_orig"
        self.tk.call("rename", self._w, self._orig)
        self.tk.createcommand(self._w, self._proxy)

    def _proxy(self, *args):
        # let the actual widget perform the requested action
        cmd = (self._orig,) + args
        result = self.tk.call(cmd)

        # generate an event if something was added or deleted,
        # or the cursor position changed
        if (args[0] in ("insert", "replace", "delete") or 
            args[0:3] == ("mark", "set", "insert") or
            args[0:2] == ("xview", "moveto") or
            args[0:2] == ("xview", "scroll") or
            args[0:2] == ("yview", "moveto") or
            args[0:2] == ("yview", "scroll")
        ):
            self.event_generate("<<Change>>", when="tail")

        # return what the actual widget returned
        return result 


class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.text = CustomText(self)
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical", command=self.text.yview)
        self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.text.tag_configure("bigfont", font=("Helvetica", "24", "bold"))
        self.linenumbers = TextLineNumbers(self, width=30)
        self.linenumbers.attach(self.text)

        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.linenumbers.pack(side="left", fill="y")
        self.text.pack(side="right", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.text.bind("<<Change>>", self._on_change)
        self.text.bind("<Configure>", self._on_change)

        self.text.insert("end", "one\ntwo\nthree\n")
        self.text.insert("end", "four\n",("bigfont",))
        self.text.insert("end", "five\n")

    def _on_change(self, event):
        self.linenumbers.redraw()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Это кстати более правильное решение: работает и с включенными переносами строк.

Comment: @insolor Ну решение не мое ;) Ну кстати вы обычно мои ответы критиковали...

Comment: Да, я видел ссылку на источник. По поводу критики - личность отвечающего не имеет значения.

Comment: @insolor Это конечно хорошее правило, но тут все равно все люди, кроме духа, конечно. Так что все равно смотришь, кто отвечает.

Comment: Если ответ хороший, то я просто плюсую. Если ответ плохой - обычно пишу что не так. Вы думаете лучше было бы если бы я молча минусовал? *Вот молодежь пошла - и когда минусуют молча им не так, и когда критика без минуса - тоже не так.*